# What does tar -pcf mean?

Tags: tar

This is what is have now :

```
find /home/a -mtime -1 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 tar -pcf $file01| tee -a $LOGFILE 2>&1
```

I do understand what `tar -cf` is but what is `tar -pcf`?

Comment: Whenever you have a question about what a command line tool option means, you can run `man command` to see the command's manual. In this case running `man tar` would have given you the answer.

Comment: [obligatory](https://xkcd.com/1168/).

Comment: run `--help` first then run `man` if you need information

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `-p` flag is not useful when *creating* an archive (with `-c`), only when extracting (with `-x`).

---

From the GNU `tar` manual:

> `-p`, `--preserve-permissions`, `--same-permissions`
>
> extract information about file permissions (default for superuser)

That's a horrible way of saying "preserve permissions and ownerships".

From [the OpenBSD manual](http://man.openbsd.org/tar):

> `-p`
>
> Preserve user and group ID as well as file mode regardless of the
>                current `umask(2)`.  The `setuid` and `setgid` bits are only preserved
>                if the user and group ID could be preserved.  Only meaningful in
>                conjunction with the `-x` flag.

Comment: So it doesn't make sense while creating a tar file? cant one preserve file permission while creating it?

Comment: @Innov It is my understanding that they are always preserved when creating an archive.

Answer (score 3):

From `man tar`:

```
   -p, --preserve-permissions
          extract  information  about  file permissions (default for superuser)
```

i.e. the `-p` flag makes sure file permissions (chmod modes) and ownership (user and group) are preserved.